# Android: ListView covers everything

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-linearlayout

I am using a `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout` and below that another `LinearLayout`, which won't show up because the `ListView` appears to take up all the space.

### Code:

```
listView = new ListView(this);
listView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
listLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
listLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
listLayout.addView(listView);
listLayout.addView(new NavigationBar(this, "android.intent.action.MAIN", "android.intent.action.MY_ACTIVITY"));
setContentView(listLayout);
```

`NavigationBar` is also a LinearLayout containing some buttons.
If added on its one it just play properly if added after the `ListView` it doesnt display at all.

Comment: you missed setlayoutparams for listlayout.  It is better to use layout file for gui development

Answer (score 0):

You should set the weight attribute for the linear layouts or use fixed height for the listview. Please post the xml layout to help understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
listView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

to

```
listView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1));
```

(assuming you've imported LinearLayout's LayoutParams, otherwise it will be `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams`)

This will mean the list view itself won't take up any vertical space, so the navigation bar can be laid out to how big it wants to be, but then, any free space will be assigned to the list view because it has a weight.

You should also consider not having the navigation bar at the bottom, that is a very iPhone thing to do.